# Azure Data Factory Salesforce to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

Does anybody work with Azure Data Factory V2 and with Salesforce? I need some protips with data migration between two orgs in Salesforce. Thank you for help! :)

Comment: Ref: [Copy data from and to Salesforce by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce)?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Radosław Mikołajczyk, you could learn from this Stack Overflow FQA https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the Data Factory document: [Copy data from and to Salesforce by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce).

This article outlines how to use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data from and to Salesforce. It builds on the Copy Activity overview article that presents a general overview of the copy activity.

Hope this helps.